# Are humans getting taller, shorter, staying the same height?

Tags: human-biology, human-evolution

This post stems from [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/65138/has-the-gestation-pregnancy-period-for-humans-always-been-9-months) question, and specifically [this](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/gestation.htm) article, which was provided within a response.

From what I gathered, the article attempts to make a correlation between the size of a creature and the length of its gestation period, with there being a linear, positive correlation.

This then led me to the question of, **have *homo sapiens* more or less maintained the same [average] height since the advent of our species?** In my searches I was able to find a few articles (e.g., [here](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20150513-will-humans-keep-getting-taller)), however, they mostly only consider height changes within the past 100-200 years. Ideally, I would like to know if there have been significant changes (>13 cm) in average height for *homo sapiens* **over the past 150,000 to 200,000 years**.

Comment: I think that getting a global mean human height is nigh impossible.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with kmm. However, You could probably find heights of specific genetic groups (can't remember the word for them) over time a bit easier.

Comment: This is not an answer: There has been a significant change in average height in Swedish males between 1850 (167.4 cm) and 2004 (180.2 cm). The reason we know this is the compulsory draft conscription and the records kept. To my mind mind the reason is probably changes in nutrition and health care. I would guess that the introduction of farming about 10000 years ago (take or add a few thousand years) increased human population and probably changed average height. My guess is that it initially decreased average height.